# non-Static Implicit Operator

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, implicit

Does anyone have an eloquent solution for the lack of support of non-static implicit operators in C#?  The following codes shows my current problem:

```
    class Foo
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }

        public Foo()
        {                    
        }

        public static implicit operator Foo(Bar b)
        {
            Foo newFoo = new Foo();
            newFoo.y = b.y;
            return newFoo;
        }
    }

    class Bar
    {
        public int y { get; set; }

        public Bar()
        {
        }
    }

    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.x = 42;
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.y = 52;
    foo = bar;

    Console.WriteLine(foo.x); // THIS PRINTS 0
```

Here is the functionality I am looking for:

```
     public implicit operator Foo(Bar b)
     {
         this.y = b.y;
     }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fortunately, you can't do this. I say "fortunately" because it's *very confusing* for the reader. I suggest you just write a method instead, e.g. `MergeFrom`, so that you're code then reads:

```
// Object initializers used for readability.
Foo foo = new Foo { x = 42 };
Bar bar = new Bar { y = 52 };
foo.MergeFrom(bar);
```

That's *much* clearer in terms of intent, IMO.

The assignment operator *always* sets the value of the variable on the left hand side to the value on the right hand side - possibly via conversion, but *never* based on the existing value of the variable on the left hand side. That's just how the language works - and you're trying to change that.

Don't fight against the language: anyone reading the code won't thank you for it. Instead, work *with* the idioms of the language.

If you *really* want to use operators of some kind, you could always overload the `+` operator:

```
public implicit operator +(Foo lhs, Bar rhs)
{
    return new Foo { x = lhs.x, y = rhs.y };
}
```

Then you can use:

```
foo += bar;
```

... which again is clearer that the final value of `foo` depends on the existing value.

Comment: The `+=` option is interesting, though it's still quite confusing in this case, since you'd probably intuitively expect it to add the two y values together.

Comment: @DanBryant: Yes, it wouldn't be my first choice either, to be honest. I like the explicit nature of `MergeFrom`.